# How to select rows for 10 secs interval from CSV(pandas) based on time stamps

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to get break my CSV based on timestamps I am getting. I want to slice the rows from 00:00:00:000 to 00:00:10:000, then from 00:00:10:000 to 00:00:20:000 then 00:00:20:000 to 00:00:30:000 and likewise...

```
    time         2ndColumn                  3rdColumn 
0  0:00:45.817    Siulaim                  first lupoK           
1  0:00:48.553     Lexcon                   ghdhsvaasd          
2  0:00:51.546  brunoalva                       hello?           
3  0:00:56.130       Snko                          Pog
4  0:01:00.342    mcdizzo                       hfgjsa
```

I want 0th and 1st row should come as one, then 2 and 3 in one then further as 10 secs gap.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.set_index('time').resample('10s').apply(list)
```

outputs:

```
                          2ndColumn                  3rdColumn
time
2019-11-22 00:00:40  [Siulaim, Lexcon]  [first lupoK, ghdhsvaasd]
2019-11-22 00:00:50  [brunoalva, Snko]              [hello?, Pog]
2019-11-22 00:01:00          [mcdizzo]                   [hfgjsa]
```

or use `sum()` for:

```
df.set_index('time').resample('10s').sum()
                         2ndColumn              3rdColumn
time
2019-11-22 00:00:40  SiulaimLexcon  first_lupoKghdhsvaasd
2019-11-22 00:00:50  brunoalvaSnko              hello?Pog
2019-11-22 00:01:00        mcdizzo                 hfgjsa
```

you can reset index after if you dont want time as index